# How to have spotify write music meta data from gracenote locally

Tags: spotify

I'm having spotify update the meta-data on my music using gracenote, however, its not writing those changes locally on my drive. How can I force it to do so. Or is there any other software that will do this for me? I'm very impressed with this automatic change as most of my 5K songs are tagged correctly now.
I'm using Windows 7 and have around 5K = 28 GB of music. I've closed and opened it multiple times and have checked and unchecked the itunes and WM player sources. I am a free user.